# how to get the value from xml node in jlinq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2013

I am using the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing to merge the document in C#.

The xml node is like that:

```
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  ORDERType  \* MERGEFORMAT </w:instrText>
```

I need to get all node has attribute `instrText`.  How can I get the value "MERGEFIELD  ORDERType  * MERGEFORMAT "

There is my code:

```
public XNamespace XMLNS { get { return XNamespace.Get(WORDMLNS); } }

public const string WORDMLNS = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

// Open Template
function getDoc(String Template){
    byte[] sourceBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Template.FullName);
    using (MemoryStream _workingMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Load into memory
        _workingMemoryStream.Write(sourceBytes, 0, sourceBytes.Length);

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_workingMemoryStream, true))
        {
            XElement newBody = XElement.Parse(wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.OuterXml);

            // I didn't get any of the node
            IList<XElement> mailMergeFields =
                (from el in newBody.Descendants()
                 where el.Attribute(XMLNS + "instrText") != null
                 select el).ToList();

            // Replace all merge fields with Data
            foreach (XElement field in mailMergeFields)
            {
                    //do something
            }
     }
}
```

Would someone tell me how to use xml.linq to get the value of "MERGEFIELD  ORDERType  * MERGEFORMAT". Thanks in advance

Comment: In your sample XML `instrText` is an element, not an attribute. That might be the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, thanks. I can get the valueby using the code:   IList<XElement> mailMergeFields =
                       (from el in newBody.Descendants
                        (XMLNS.GetName("instrText"))
                        select el).ToList();